# Headphones controls not working with xperia ray

Tags: headphones, sony-ericsson-xperia-ray

I have Marshall minor headphones with microphone and control buttons for music.
I am using these with my Sony Ericsson Ray but I am unable to use the microphone on the headphones.
When I plug the headphones into my phone it comes up with `accessory not supported`.
So I have to use an adaptor/converter but this only allows me to listen to my headphones, not use the controls on them? How can I fix this?

Comment: You might like to read http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24559/headphone-music-controls-not-working-correctly from the 'related questions' list.

Answer (score 0):

The Ray's 3.5mm jack only supports sound. It isn't a microphone jack.